# find string containing alphanumeric value in sas

Tags: database, sas, dataset

I want to find variable containing alphanumeric values like 123asd or numeric value 123 upto 9 any combination of 1 to 9.  If there is present then create new column with 'found' text.

code :

```
 data one;
 input Val $;

 datalines;
 abc.400
 300.bef
 3456321
 abcdefg
 123.234
 ;

 proc print;
 run;
```

output should be

```
  value    tag
 abc.400  found
 300.bef  found
 3456321  found
 abcdefg  nofound
 123.234  found
```

Answer (score 3):

Anydigit function.

```
flag=ifc(anydigit(Val)>0,'Found','NoFound');
```

Comment: its giving me an error called the function ifc is unknown or cannot be accessed .

Comment: also want to show not found if their size is less than 7 characters
example : 
Val                       tag
21312   Not found

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compress()` and the `kd` (keep digits) third argument, and then `missing()` to see if that return anything.  I put it in a one-liner with `ifc` which is an excel-style if (returns 2nd argument if true, 3rd argument if false), returns character).

```
tag = ifc(missing(compress(value,,'kd')),'nofound','found')
```